# SQL Server 2008 using a function within a sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fncGetCustInfo] (@IShopID int)
RETURNS

@CustomerInfo table (ShopID int, CustID int)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @CustomerInfo
SELECT  ShopID,
CustomerID
FROM dbo.ShopTbl
WHERE ShopID= @IShopID  
RETURN
END
```

and this is is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetCustomerInfo]

@IShopID int 
as
BEGIN

declare @CustomerName varchar(50), @ShopD int, @CustomerID int, @Date date

--Return the customer ids using the function I have created
SELECT @CustomerID = fncGetCustInfo.CustomerID FROM dbo.fncGetCustInfo(@IShopID)
--Set the customer names column using the customer ids I retrived using my function
SELECT @CustomerName = CustomerName
from dbo.CustomerTbl
where CustomerID = @CustomerID

Select @Date = GETDATE()

END
```

My question is about this line in the sproc:

```
SELECT @CustomerID = fncGetCustInfo.CustomerID FROM dbo.fncGetCustInfo(@IShopID)
```

Will this return me the CustomerIDs from the table I create in the function called CustomerInfo by calling the function I created earlier

Comment: What is the question? I am missing something. This could be simplified but I don't quite get the part about getting names and such.

Comment: I haven't got access to the tables to run it

Comment: You can't assign multiple ids to a scalar variable. You'll only grab the "last" one with that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do see things my answer will be yes but instead of creating a function to return that result I will embed the function within the proc this way:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetCustomerInfo]
(

@IShopID int 
)
as
BEGIN

declare @CustomerName varchar(50),  @CustomerID int, @Date date   

SET @CustomerID = (SELECT TOP 1 ShopID,CustomerID FROM dbo.ShopTbl WHERE ShopID= @IShopID)


--Set the customer names column using the customer ids I retrived using my     
SELECT @CustomerName = CustomerName
from dbo.CustomerTbl
where CustomerID = @CustomerID

Select @Date = GETDATE()

END
```

Unless you are going to use the function in a different place but also keep in mind that function can create performance issues.

Comment: also doing a LEFT JOIN with those tables (ShopTbl, CustomerTbl) could also suffice what's you are trying to do but not sure what's the logic in place